# Inserting new rows and generate a new id based on the current last row

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

The primary key of my table is an Identity column of an ID. I want to be able to insert a new row and have it know what the last ID in the table currently is and add one to it. I know I can use Scope Identity to get the last inserted column from my code, but I am worried about people manually adding entries in the database, because they do this quite often. Is there a way I can look at the last ID in the table and not just the last ID my code inserted?

Comment: If they insert manually a record where there is an identity column they cannot insert their own number unless they disable the IDENTITY. So what is the problem?

Comment: By the way, I assume you are using Sql Server because you talk about IDENTITY columns and not MySql. Right?

Comment: IDENTITY automatically does this. No extra action needed. That's the use of the IDENTITY property. `SELECT MAX(ID) FROM YourTable` will give you the maximum value if you need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a [SQL Identity column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property), you don't need to do anything special. This is the default behavior. SQL Server will handle making sure you don't have collisions regardless of where the inserts come from.

The `@@Identity` will pull the latest identity, and [scope_identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql) will grab the identity from the current scope.

> A scope is a module: a stored procedure, trigger, function, or batch. Therefore, if two statements are in the same stored procedure, function, or batch, they are in the same scope.

Comment: Yes, this was my mistake. I did not realize this. It wasn't originally an identity column, so I wasn't able to insert without an ID, but now I can. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to allow manual entries to the primary column, then you can add `Identity` constraint to it along with `primary key` constraint.

Example, while creating a table,

```
CREATE Table t_Temp(RowID Int Primary Key Identity(1,1), Name Varchar(50))

INSERT Into t_Temp values ('UserName')
INSERT Into t_Temp values ('UserName1')

SELECT * from t_Temp
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can query the table and get the next available code in one SQL query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(CAST("RowID" AS INT)),0) +1 as 'NextRowID' from <tableName>
```

The "0" here is a default, meaning if there are no rows found, the first code returned would be (0+1) =1

Generally I have 999 instead of the 0 as I like my RowID/primary key etc. to start at 1000.